# MVC Razor with a table element and a list of objects with a list of objects inside

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a list of objects with a list of objects inside.

I have a table and trying to show the list and the list inside.

I get a red squiggly under the 2nd @foreach of the embedded list and a parse error when calling the controller function from JavaScript in a .cshtml.

[image]

Why is this invalid?
I tried putting it into a row tag, but no luck.

```html
@model IEnumerable<DashBoard.Models.CustomerOrdersViewModel>
@using DashBoard.Helpers;

<table class="table table-hover">
    @foreach (var mdHeader in Model)
    {
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Customer Name</td>
                <td>Customer Image</td>
                <td>Order Date</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>@mdHeader.CustomerName</td>
            <td><img class="rounded img-thumbnail" src="@string.Format("/Images/Customers/{0}", @mdHeader.CustomerImage)" alt="" style="width:50px; height:60px;" /></td>
            <td>@mdHeader.OrderDate</td>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var mdDetail in mdHeader.OrderDetailsViewModel)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@mdDetail.Quantity</td>
                <td>@mdDetail.ProductName</td>
                @* Concern: How is the path to the image determined? *@
                <td>@Html.ProductImage(@mdDetail.ProductType, @mdDetail.ProductImage, "60px", "58px") </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Comment: "I get a red squiggly"...and what error is associated with that? That's the important detail, not whether the line is squiggly or not :-) . I think you can probably just drop the `@`, though?

Comment: P.S. I'm going to bet the error says `"Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "foreach" with "@". ` Which should give you a pretty big clue as to what to do...

Comment: The error from JavaScript stated a "parse error"..and html. Really no usable details. I will include it above. But per your suggestion, removing the @ did the job. Thanks!

Comment: ADyson..I'd like to check your as the answer, but can't do it as is. Thanks again though.

Comment: That's because I only commented. It's such a trivial thing I didn't really think it was worthy of an answer, it's more or less just a typo IMO. P.S. that error I quoted would be in Visual Studio while you're writing the code, not in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already has the @ against the first foreach. You shouldn't need it against the second. Remove it.